# logo for clothing brand using 3d block

Tags: logo, 3d, branding, apparel

I'm designing a clothing brand logo and it uses a 3D children's toy block. We've looked at other clothing logos but none are in 3D. Is it ok to use a 3D object in a clothing brand logo?

Comment: Yes, it's quite fine. The only thing I'd make sure though, is that the logo ends up being vector in the end, rather than a raster image of a 3D rendering. Which would often mean that if you originally make it in 3D application, you'd potentially need to recreate it or at least finalize it in something like Illustrator.

Comment: I've made it in illustrator so its vector, using the extrude bevel function with mapped sides. do you know any examples of good logos that use 3d?

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't think of many, but let's see: The previous pepsi logo used to be 3D, A really old pepsi logo used to be a bottle cap from a perspective, AT & T, Sony Ericsson, Rhino 3D, Solidworks logo used to be a 3d cube, Cinema 4D, SketchUp, Volkswagen, Citroen, Audi.

Comment: @Joonas, why isn't that an answer? I'd +1 it.

Comment: @Bakabaka Because reasons... Fine, I'll make it into an answer, but it's not going to be a good one.

Comment: ...or maybe it will be... Haha!

Comment: cool thanks, do you know any clothing brand logos that are 3d?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it be OK?

Comment: because there's practically no existing 3d clothing logos that i can find. So i figured there might be a reason why none have tried to use a 3d logo

Answer (score 3):

[My comment](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35341/logo-for-clothing-brand-using-3d-block#comment48892_35341) as an answer:

Yes, it's quite fine.

**The only thing I'd make sure though, is that the logo ends up being vector in the end**, rather than a raster image of a 3D rendering.

Which would often mean that if you originally make it in 3D application, you'd potentially need to recreate it or at least finalize it in something like Illustrator.

---

Depenping on how much of a 3D look I'm going for, I would use a 3D rendering as my "guide" to recreate it in Illustrator ( Just a quick render ) or just a 3D model converted into 2D line drawing. If possible, I would use both methods together.

Comment: Or you can just let your 3D application render vector art.

Comment: @joojaa Mmmaybe, but it's not always an option or ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You also want to have a good understanding of all the mediums where the logo is going to be used. For instance, on the web or 4-color printing, where the skies the limit for color, a 3D logo isn't an issue.

However, if the client wants the logo inside the shirt (where the size goes), or screen printed on the front of a shirt, a 3D logo would be expensive to produce.

My suggestion is to make a 3D logo that also has a compelling flat version of it, in case the client has to pay-per-color. You also want to make sure it can be produced in black and white.